# Display contents of files which are greater than 0

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a shell script. 
I have bunch of files in a directory. From there, I need to display content of files which are greater than 0 bytes in size. and delete the files which are 0 in size.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Luckily, since files of zero size have no content, you can easily display the content of the non-zero size files with `cat *`

Answer (score 3):

I Found an answer which works fine. But, any more inputs will be welcome.
The answer is the following. Which I need to use in shell script.

```
find . -size 0c -delete
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines `find ./ -empty -exec rm {} \;` 6 of one half a dozen of the other. Then you can just cat the remaining files after that to "Display the contents of non-0 byte files"

Comment: `-delete` is more efficient if your version of `find` supports it (no external processes to spawn), but even `find ./ -empty -exec rm {} +` would cut down on the number of separate calls to `rm` while remaining POSIX-compliant. `-empty` is also a GNU extension, although I don't know that it has any benefit over `-size 0c` other than readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will work

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(ls) ; do
  if [ -f $f ] ; then
    if [ -s $f ] ; then
      ls $f
    else
      rm $f
    fi
  fi
done
```

Note, it's just doing `ls` in the current directory. You could also pass in a directory as arg to look in or other method. Also, this won't pick up hidden files (`.*`).

The key to how it works are the Bash conditional expressions `-s` (true if file is more than 0 size) and `-f` (true if regular file).

Comment: You want `cat`, not `ls`, to display the *contents* of a non-empty file.

Answer (score 0):

To display the contents of all files under `topdir` that have non-zero size:

```
find topdir -type f \! -size 0c -exec cat {} +
```

To delete all completely empty files under the same directory:

```
find topdir -type f -size 0c -ok rm {} \;
```

Replace `-ok` with `-exec` (and the `\;` at the end to `+`) if you don't want to confirm each removal.

This solution assumes a POSIX `find`.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in `ls` ; do
    if [ -s $i ] ; then
        cat $i
    else
        rm -f $i
    fi
 done
```

if you have spaces in you filenames you may need to change IFS env variable, or think about using "find" command instead

Comment: Don't use the output of `ls` in a script, and don't iterate over the output of a command with `for`.

Comment: @chepner: don't be an ass and at least give a reason. Or should I think the reason is "because chepner said so"?

Comment: Do a search for any question or answer involving `ls`. It's not a big secret that this is a bad idea. Consider learning about the shell before answer; it gets tiring pointing out the same bad practices over and over.

Comment: I mentioned possible need of of using IFS variable, so the ls is completely alright

Comment: No, it isn't. What if you have a file named `*`? That will expand to the full list of files *again*. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.